# How to convert this sql from SAS to Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

The sql below is working in sas but doesn't work in AWS Athena.
I got a 'EXPRESSION_NOT_AGGREGATE' error message.

I don't want to return any aggregate expression in the result.
How should I do?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    VAR_A
    ,VAR_B
    ,VAR_C
FROM data_org
WHERE VAR_D in ('3', '8')
GROUP BY VAR_A
HAVING VAR_E = MAX(VAR_E)
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output describing what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, all non-aggregated columns have to be part of the `group by` clause. You aren't (and don't want to) aggregate anything, so get rid of that clause (along with `having`) and switch to `where`:

```
select distinct var_a, var_b, var_c
from data_org
where var_d in ('3', '8')
  and var_e = (select max(var_e) 
               from data_org);
```

Comment: You are not taking the max per value of VAR_A.  You are not taking the max of only the observations with the right values of var_d.

Comment: That's how I understood the question, @Tom. You might be right, so - thank you for a comment. Sample data and desired result (posted by the OP) would certainly help.

Answer (score 0):

It may work in sas but normal SQL require som aggregate functions (MAX, MIN, AVG, SUM, etc) in the select part of the query if you are grouping, and anything that's not an aggregate needs be grouped by.

So you need to add som aggregate to your SELECT part and make sure the GROUP BY includes the columns not using aggregates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    VAR_A
    ,VAR_B
    ,VAR_C
    ,MAX(VAR_F) --or something else
FROM data_org
WHERE VAR_D in ('3', '8')
GROUP BY VAR_A, VAR_B, VAR_C --include everything not having Aggregate function
HAVING VAR_E = MAX(VAR_E)
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS's PROC SQL will happily remerge summary statistics, like the `max(var_e)` in your example, with the detailed rows.  Other SQL implementations are not so user friendly and you will have to remerge the aggregate values yourself.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      a.VAR_A
    , a.VAR_B
    , a.VAR_C
FROM data_org a
  inner join
     (select var_a, max(var_e) as max_e 
        from data_org 
        where VAR_D in ('3', '8')
        group by var_a
     ) b
on  a.var_a = b.var_a
and a.var_e = b.max_e
and a.VAR_D in ('3', '8')
```